# Change of variable x=iy in improper integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Let $I=\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-x^4)dx$. Take $x=i y$ to get $i\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-y^4)dy=i I$. Explain.

This change of variable implies $I=iI$, with $I$ real, so $I=0$, which is wrong. I have to explain why this change of the integral does not work.
Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

Comment: You have to use a correct substitution (i.e. you forgot to change the integral bounds)

Comment: What does this substitution mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have found, rather, is that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_0^{i R} dy \, e^{-y^4} = -i \int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-x^4}$$

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it. Is it correct that the proposed change of variable does not work because the bounds of the integral are not changed?

Comment: @user95864: No.  My point is that the integration path has changed - by making this substitution, you have extended it into the complex plane.

Comment: Ok, but what would be the reason to extend it into the complex plane?

Comment: @user95864: your substitution.  You specified that the integral be taken along the imaginary axis.  Now you have an integral in the complex plane.  It is not the same as the integral on the real line.  You can try to relate the two by Cauchy's theorem, but this is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something more "pedestrian"?:

$$u=x^4\implies dx=\frac{du}{4 u^{3/4}}\implies \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-x^4}dx=\frac14\int\limits_0^\infty u^{-3/4}e^{-u}du=\frac14\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)=\Gamma\left(\frac54\right)$$

Comment: I don't think this is the issue here.  I think's he has found an apparent contradiction and wants it explained.

Comment: Perhaps, and then the first comment and your answer wraps it all.